# How is resource preserved between HTTP requests in Python web framework?

Tags: python, flask

I'm actually new to Python web development. My previous knowledge about web development came from PHP.

In PHP, there's no resource (variable etc.) preserved between two different HTTP requests (except for `$_SESSION` I guess?)

So if `Flask` is run by `gunicorn`, what resource is preserved between two different HTTP requests?

This question came from [the document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlalchemy/) of `Flask`. In the document, it says we need to register database session close code in `app.teardown_request`. In my own test, if I didn't register the session close code, the database will get many idle connection.

Answer (score 0):

There are really only two modes of handling web requests:

1. Spin up the entire application for each request and tear it down after each request.  Everything that isn't persisted (to some other process, to disk, or to the client) is *destroyed* at the end of the request.
2. Spin up the application and then let it handle more than one request before it gets torn down. Almost everything that isn't specific to the request is *preserved* between requests.

Mode #1 has more work to do for each request but it ensures that all resources that the application uses are torn down (so you don't have problems with leaking database connections, even if you forget to close them).

Mode #2 has less work to do for each request but it is possible for an application to "leak" resources - as in your example where you leak database connections if you don't explicitly close them.

PHP (running in embedded mode in Apache under `mod_php`) uses the first mode.  Flask (and frameworks in the majority of languages commonly used for web development these days) uses the second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If in Python, most resources are preserved between requests, how can I use a previously defined variable?

Comment: @yegle - My use of "application" was a bit unclear. Most resources that the *web-framework* uses are preserved between requests.  If you need to preserve, say a pool of database connections between requests then you would need to store it at the framework level.

Comment: this is what confusing me. Is there any resource that's preserved in framework by default? Or it's a per-framework behavior?

Comment: @yegle - most of the time the information that is expensive to *generate* is preserved.  For example, the maps between routes and functions, the templating environment, etc.